# php download mail attachment without function

Tags: php, email, imap, gmail-imap

I would like to download the attachment by PHP from an e-mail address to the server where the PHP script is located. The script runs smoothly, but it does not load anything down.

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(3000);  
$hostname = '{******************************}INBOX'; 
$username = '*****@**********.de'; # e.g somebody@gmail.com 
$password = '*****************'; 


/* try to connect */ 
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error()); 


/* get all new emails. If set to 'ALL' instead  
 * of 'NEW' retrieves all the emails, but can be  
 * resource intensive, so the following variable,  
 * $max_emails, puts the limit on the number of emails downloaded. 
 *  
 */ 
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL'); 

/* useful only if the above search is set to 'ALL' */ 
$max_emails = 16; 


/* if any emails found, iterate through each email */ 
if($emails) { 

    $count = 1; 

    /* put the newest emails on top */ 
    rsort($emails); 

    /* for every email... */ 
    foreach($emails as $email_number)  
    { 

        /* get information specific to this email */ 
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0); 

        /* get mail message */ 
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2); 

        /* get mail structure */ 
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number); 

        $attachments = array(); 

        /* if any attachments found... */ 
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts))  
        { 
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++)  
            { 
                $attachments[$i] = array( 
                    'is_attachment' => false, 
                    'filename' => '', 
                    'name' => '', 
                    'attachment' => '' 
                ); 

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters)  
                { 
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object)  
                    { 
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename')  
                        { 
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true; 
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters)  
                { 
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object)  
                    { 
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name')  
                        { 
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true; 
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment'])  
                { 
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1); 

                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */ 
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3)  
                    {  
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']); 
                    } 
                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */ 
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4)  
                    {  
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */ 
        foreach($attachments as $attachment) 
        { 
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1) 
            { 
                $filename = $attachment['name']; 
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename']; 

                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat"; 

                /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails 
                 * have the attachment with the same file name. 
                 */ 
                $fp = fopen($filename, "w+");    // $email_number . "-" .  
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']); 
                fclose($fp); 
            } 

        } 

        if($count++ >= $max_emails) break; 
    } 

}  

/* close the connection */ 
imap_close($inbox); 

echo "Done"; 

?>
```

No attachment is downloaded. The script binds neatly. Can Please help me?

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? You probably want to write the files into another directory for security, though that directory will vary depending on the server configuration and your privileges. Currently you have it set to write to the same directory as the PHP code, so an attachment with a .php extension would open a wonderful security hole.

Comment: That is correct. However, it should be limited so that only CSV files are downloaded from a specific e-mail address. In addition, the server can not be reached except from an IP lock. On the server in the same directory can be written, that is not the problem. An error message I get not at all. Get a "DONE" and that's it.

Comment: Then I would work through it piece by piece with a bunch of print statements to figure out where the code really goes. The problem could be anything from mail server login to message processing to attachment formats, etc.

Comment: When I send an e-mail with any attachment via Outlook, it downloads the attachment. The e-mail comes daily, but he does not download it. This is sent by a server!

Comment: Back to my previous statement: "work through it piece by piece with a bunch of print statements to figure out where the code really goes". I have found that different email programs (Outlook, Thunderbird, PHP scripts, Python scripts, etc.) handle attachments in a number of different ways.

Comment: Perfect. Working. `$hostname = '{******************************}INBOX';` "INBOX" not need.  should be `$hostname = '{mail.server.com}';` something like that.